# File.delete doesn't delete file

Tags: java, java-io, filewriter

In a unit test I create a file in the temp folder, after the tests I want to delete them.

```
 @After
    public void destroy() throws IOException {
        if (!new File(tempFile.toAbsolutePath().getParent().toString() + "\\file1.tmp").delete()) {
            System.out.println("file1.tmp not deleted");
        }
        if (!new File(tempFile.toAbsolutePath().getParent().toString() + "\\file2.log").delete()) {
            System.out.println("file2.log not deleted");
        }
        if (!new File(tempFile.toAbsolutePath().getParent().toString() + "\\file3.log").delete()) {
            System.out.println("file3.log not deleted");
        }
        if (!new File(tempFile.toAbsolutePath().getParent().toString() + "\\file4.log").delete()) {
            System.out.println("file4.log not deleted");
        }
    }
```

It deletes the files 1-3 without a single problem but I doensn't delete file4.
Normally File.delete should throw an IOException but it just returns false.

I used the same method for each file, the writer is closed after creating and writing the files.

I hope I didn't forget any information

Comment: `File.delete()` does not throw `IOException`s. It returns `false` upon a failure to delete. You can use the `delete()` method from the `java.nio.Files` class if you want an exception that might give you an indication of the cause.

Comment: What makes you think that it should throw an IOException? The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete()) does not mention that.

Comment: What is now the question? Why it does not throw or why the file is not deleted?

Comment: @fredrik I read the "Note"-Part wrong. I thought it means, that the delete method like I used it throws an IOException.

Comment: @Henry I wanted to know why it isn't throwing anything, sorry for not writing that directly ^^"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Normally `File.delete` should throw an `IOException` but it just returns false.

Ahem ...

`File.delete` does not throw an `IOException` if it fails to delete a file<sup>1</sup>.  It returns `false`.

As to why it is failing to delete the file, the most likely explanations are:

- The file is locked because something has it open.  Windows won't let you delete a file that is locked.
- The application doesn't have the required (OS level) access to delete the file due; i.e. it is a file or directory permission issue.

If you want to find out why the deletion is failing, the solution is to change your code to use `Path` and `Files.delete(Path)`.  The methods in `Files` are designed throw exceptions.  In this case, the message should give the reason for the failure to delete.

---

<sup>1 - The only exception that the method is documented as throwing is `SecurityException` which will only be thrown if there is a `SecurityManager` active.</sup>

Comment: Thank you, now I see the Exception. It was the Reader before, I didn't close it. Thank you very much. Sorry, can't upvote at the moment, need more reputation.